# DXVK doesn't install in wine prefix

Tags: command-line, wine, tar, winetricks

i recently installed spitfire audio app using wine.  The app has graphical issues. i was told to install dxvk, but when i did, winetricks returned this error:

```
Executing cd /home/USERNAME/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp
Executing tar -zxf /home/USERNAME/.cache/winetricks/dxvk/dxvk-2.2.tar.gz

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
------------------------------------------------------
warning: Note: command tar -zxf /home/USERNAME/.cache/winetricks/dxvk/dxvk-2.2.tar.gz returned status 2. Aborting.
```

I am not that learned in linux, but i hope this gives enough info. Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, it means that the tarball containing DXVK for Wine to use/install is nonfunctional.  Usually means you have a bad tarball or it's not available anymore.  Unfortunately, this is a hard Wine bug and not something that's *easily* fixable and can *only* be fixed by the DXVK  and Wine devs.

Comment: okay, thank you for that info.